# String becomes undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
bot.addListener('message', function (from, channel, message) {
    IRClog.write("[" + (new Date()).toJSON() + "] [" + channel + "] <" + from + ">" + message + "\n");
    // ============= PLAYER COMMANDS ============= //
    if (logMessages){
        util.log("[" + channel + "] <" + from + ">" + message);
    }
    console.log(message)// the message is logged
    bot.whois(from,function(WHOIS){
        if(typeof WHOIS.account == 'undefined'){
            var isAuthed = false;
        } else {
            var isAuthed = true;
        }
        if (message.indexOf("!") === 0){//now the message is undefined
                    ...
```

As described in the code, the var message is a string, and then, I don't know why, it becomes an undefined variable. Why is that happening? I didn't assign it to another value.

Comment: JavaScript has dynamic scoping, so when `bot.whois` is executed the `message` variable may not be defined in the scope context. The solution is to pass in the `message` rather than depending on the variable being in scope.

Comment: And how do I do that?

Comment: You can use a closure.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the execution context the `function` that the `bot.whois` executes may not have `message` defined in scope. You can use a closure to ensure the scope by passing in the `message`.

```
(function (msg) {
    console.log(msg)// the message is logged
    bot.whois(from, function(WHOIS){
        var isAuthed = typeof WHOIS.account !== 'undefined';
        if (msg.indexOf("!") === 0) {
            ...
        }
})(message);
```

Comment: No, if the `bot.whois` handler function is created inside the `bot.addListener` handler function, then `message` _will_ be in scope. There is no way to prevent it unless you overwrite it. And in fact, `message` is already being closed over just like you suggest by passed to the outer function as an argument on the first line.

Comment: Didn't work. Tried with:  
console.log(msg);  
 (function (message) {  
  console.log(message);  
  bot.whois(from,function(WHOIS){  
   console.log(message);  
Logs:string,string,undefined

Comment: You can edit that into your question. It would also help to have a more complete code sample.

Comment: @AlexWayne `message` is in scope, but it's not local, so it can be changed from an external scope (which seems to be the case).  The closure should rectify that, though it's not the only way to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is incomplete, obviously, and the actual bug probably resides somewhere below your cutoff point as you've put in your question:

```
bot.addListener('message', function (from, channel, message) {
    IRClog.write("[" + (new Date()).toJSON() + "] [" + channel + "] <" + from + ">" + message + "\n");
    // ============= PLAYER COMMANDS ============= //
    if (logMessages){
        util.log("[" + channel + "] <" + from + ">" + message);
    }
    console.log(message)// the message is logged
    bot.whois(from,function(WHOIS){
        if(typeof WHOIS.account == 'undefined'){
            var isAuthed = false;
        } else {
            var isAuthed = true;
        }
        if (message.indexOf("!") === 0){//now the message is undefined
                    ...
    }); // end of the whois block, which is asynchronous

    /* somewhere down here, message probably gets set to undefined
    like this:
    message = undefined; // this would run before bot.whois(from, cb); finishes
    */
}); // end of addListener
```

You either need to make sure that you're not messing with the message below your `whois` call, or you need to create a copy that you don't mess with, or you need to follow @Romoku's advice and wrap your `whois` call in a properly formatted closure (like the following) and pass message in to a strictly local scope:

```
bot.addListener('message', function (from, channel, message) {
    IRClog.write("[" + (new Date()).toJSON() + "] [" + channel + "] <" + from + ">" + message + "\n");
    // ============= PLAYER COMMANDS ============= //
    if (logMessages){
        util.log("[" + channel + "] <" + from + ">" + message);
    }
    console.log(message)// the message is logged
    (function (msg) {
        bot.whois(from,function(WHOIS){
            if(typeof WHOIS.account == 'undefined'){
                var isAuthed = false;
            } else {
                var isAuthed = true;
            }
            if (msg.indexOf("!") === 0){//now the message is undefined
                        ...
        }); // end of the whois block, which is asynchronous
    })(message);

    /* now you can do whatever you want to the message variable and bot.whois will
    be able to operate on its independent, unmolested copy
    */
}); // end of addListener
```

Please note how in my example, and @Romoku's, `message` has been explicitly renamed (to `msg` and `m`, respectively), to make it clear that you're working with in a different scope with a different copy of the data.